# Removing a Non Negativity Constraint in a Linear Programming Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let's say I have a linear programming problem, i.e.

\begin{array}{rl}
\text{maximize}  & c^T x \\
\text{subject to} & {\bf A} x \le b
\end{array}

without the non-negativity constraint on $x$ (i.e. $x \ge 0$). However, whenever I read about the linear programming, this constraint was always included. Why is that? To me, the statement above is equivalent to:

\begin{array}{rl}
\text{maximize}  & c^T x \\
\text{subject to} & {\bf A} x \le b \\
\text{and} & x \ge 0 \lor x \le 0
\end{array}

which can be considered as two, separate problems: one for $x \ge 0$ and one for $x \le 0$ (where the solutions can be combined into one). Also, the problem with the constraint $x \le 0$ can be transformed into the first one by introducing $x' = -x$. This means that I could use linear programming algorithms for solving problems without the non-negativity constraints. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that $\mathbf x$ is a vector here. So it's not true that one of the two options $\mathbf x\ge \mathbf 0$ (every component of $\mathbf x$ is nonnegative) and $\mathbf x \le \mathbf 0$ (every component of $\mathbf x$ is nonpositive) is necessarily true. We could have a mix.

Whenever we have a linear program 
\begin{align}
\max\ & \mathbf c^{\mathsf T} \mathbf x \\
\text{s.t. } & A\mathbf x  \le \mathbf b
\end{align}
we can turn it into a program in nonnegative variables by substituting $\mathbf x = \mathbf x^+ - \mathbf x^-$, where $\mathbf x^+ \ge \mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf x^- \ge 0$. (Any real number can be written as the difference of two nonnegative numbers.) So you can use LP algorithms that assume nonnegativity to solve such a program, but you will have to deal with twice as many variables.

Another option when dealing with a program like this one is to take the dual. The dual will have the form
\begin{align}
\min\ & \mathbf u^{\mathsf T} \mathbf b \\
\text{s.t. } & \mathbf u^{\mathsf T}A = \mathbf c^{\mathsf T} \\
 & \mathbf u \ge \mathbf 0
\end{align}
and so you have nonegativity constraints there.